# What was the purpose of Loki's conquest of Earth?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, marvel, thor-marvel, loki

I was re-watching the Marvel Phase 1 movies and I couldn't really understand Loki's motives for conquering Earth. During *Thor* he falls to his apparent death and in *The Avengers* we find out that he hasn't died but has been with Thanos who gives him his new sceptre and the Chitauri army to conquer the planet.

But what is Loki's plan? Isn't he after Asgard and Odin's throne, and how does Earth fit in all of this?

Comment: So ruling the entire Earth isn't good enough motive for you?

Comment: Hes jealous of his brother i guess. I think if Thor wasn't sent to earth no one would care

Comment: Loki is quite keen to rule Asgard but it looks like he'd be happy ruling at least one of the Nine Realms (one of the nice ones, anyway) as a booby prize

Comment: He wants people to bow down to him and to respect him as a king

Comment: Earth has nothing to do with Thanos' plans. Loki just wanted somewhere to rule. In exchange of Loki's services to Thanos, Thanos granted power and army for Loki. Thanos only wanted the Tesseract which Earthlings had at that time. To achieve this, he gave Loki the Scepter and the army. Loki failed anyway (or did he?)... But if we focus on the reason why Loki chose Earth to become its ruler, I'd say, it's because his jealousy of Thor. Because Thor's relationship with humans on Earth and becoming an ally to them, Loki went after the throne of Earth.

Comment: @apollo Yes, Loki failed both his own designs and the designs of Thanos; he failed to conquer Earth and he also failed to retrieve the Tesseract for Thanos. On top of that, he also lost at least a large portion of the army and the Infinity Stone inside of the staff.

Comment: @TylerH Some say he had some grand design in losing to the avengers team. He became Odin at the end of TTDW. But when you say it like that, Loki is nothing but a big bag of ducks. Lol.

Comment: @apollo I'd probably argue that becoming King of Asgard (via subterfuge or peaceful means) is a separate plan from openly conquering Earth via hostile invasion.

Comment: Does he need a reason?  Loki is basically the Joker of the MCU.  He's the Trickster God.  Sometimes he just does things for no reason because it seems like fun.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Actually, Loki is very much NOT the Joker. He is the Trickster - therefore he always has a plan. Very much the opposite of chaos, which the Joker embodies. In fact I remember an issue (seems it was Amazing Spider-man #504) where Loki actually teamed up (sorta) with Spiderman, against some magical entity who was trying to chaos-ify the universe - Loki suggested an alliance, and the Chaos God (or whatever) specifically denied him on that basis. (Spiderman on the other hand, was considered an agent of chaos, for reasons)...

Answer (score 37):

**There are multiple reasons for why Loki attacked Earth.**

The first and most obvious motive is also the simplest - **Revenge**.

From *Avengers Assemble*;

> **Thor**: We were raised together, we played together, we fought together. Do you remember none of that?
>   **Loki**: I remember a shadow, living in the shade of your greatness. I remember you tossing me into an abyss, I who was and should be king!
>   **Thor**: **So you take the world I love as recompense for your imagined slights?** No, the Earth is under MY protection, Loki!

Loki has always felt that he was over-looked by Odin in favour of Thor, the true born son of Odin and the first in line for the throne. He's jealous and angry, and he thinks that he would make a much better king than Thor would - so after Thor ruins his plan to rule Asgard (the events of *Thor*), he chooses to take revenge against his brother by attacking the world that Thor loves.

The second reason is that **he was asked to**.

A long-running but (as of yet) unresolved plot throughout the Marvel Cinematic Universe so far is that Thanos wants to unite the six Infinity Stones. One of these, the Space Gem, is stored inside the Tesseract, which the Red Skull used to power Hydra weapons in *Captain America: The First Avenger* and at the start of *Avengers Assemble* is being experimented on in SHIELD.

Thanos gifted Loki the sceptre that he wields throughout *The Avengers* in order to retrieve and return the Tesseract to him. In return, he gives Loki a Chitauri army with which to attack the planet. This is beneficial for both Thanos and Loki - Loki gains the ability to travel to Earth and an army with which to take it, and Thanos gets the Space Gem.

The third reason is a little more complicated and (as of yet) mostly guesswork - but **Loki needed to return to Asgard**.

After falling off the Bifrost Bridge, Loki had no real way to return to Asgard, the place that he wishes to rule. However, by attacking Earth (and losing the war), Thor takes him back to Asgard to be imprisoned in the dungeons. Loki later uses this imprisonment to his advantage, and as of the end of *Thor: The Dark World* actually manages to take control of Asgard without anyone knowing - becoming the King that he originally wanted to be way back in *Thor*.

How much of this was planned out in advance is still currently unknown, but knowing that Loki is the God of Mischief means that this could well be a very valid reason for why he attacked Earth - the first part in a much larger plan.

Comment: The strange thing is that Thanos thought it was a good idea to give someone an Infinity Stone so that he could go fetch another Infinity Stone. It's no wonder Thanos just sits on his chair all the time doing nothing - he's an idiot!

Answer (score 7):

According to the [junior novelisation for Avengers Assemble](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13615968-avengers), Loki's motive in trying to take over Midgard was ... erm ... so that he could take over Midgard.

> Loki was pleased. Thor and Odin thought him dead. He’d tricked them
>   when he fell from the Bifrost. They would not be interfering with his
>   plan. He’d find a way to send himself, body and soul, back to Midgard,
>   and **once he was there, he would rule these simple mortals, in a way he
>   wasn’t able to rule Asgard.**
>
> **A Realm would be his at last — just as he deserved.**

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to Dr. R Drizzle's good answer with the following Loki quotes:

> Kneel before me. I said, KNEEL! [Loki stamps his scepter on the ground, causing a shockwave that intimidates the crowd into silence as they all kneel before him] Is not this simpler? Is this not your natural state? It's the unspoken truth of humanity, that you crave subjugation. The bright lure of freedom diminishes your life's joy in a mad scramble for power, for identity. You were made to be ruled. In the end, you will always kneel.

And the memorable scene at the end of the movie before the Hulk rag-dolls Loki:

> Enough! You are, all of you are beneath me! I am a god, you dull creature, and I will not be bullied by... [Hulk smash]

Loki is a god. As such he demands worship and believes that dominating earth is simply the natural order of things.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: because Thor's girlfriend lives there.

Source: I wrote several scenes in the film version of *Thor*.  Loki threatened to pay her realm a visit after he was done (trying to) kill Thor.

edited for Blackwood:  "What happened to you on Earth to make you so soft? It was that woman?...*It was*. Maybe after I'm done here, I'll pay her a visit myself!"

hint: he wasn't bringing her flowers.

Comment: An actual quote from the script (or a transcript) would be more helpful.

Comment: The quote you added seems more like a threat against a single person rather than a whole world.